# VBA Run-time error 9 With Sheet

Tags: vba, excel, excel-2010

So here I have VBA code that is a part of my function, yet whenever I run it, I get the following error:

```
Run-Time error '9': Subscript out of range
```

The actual worksheet exists.  In the vba editor on the side panel, it appears as Sheet2(Data_Sheet).  In the details in that panel, it shows *(Name)* as being *Sheet 11* and  *Name* as being *Data_Sheet*.  Dos anybody know a possible source of this error?   My code is below:

```
With Sheets("Data_Sheet")

        'this searches just row 1
        Set header_cell_1 = .Rows(1).Find(What:="One", lookat:=xlWhole, MatchCase:=False, searchformat:=False)
        Set header_cell_2 = .Rows(1).Find(What:="Two", lookat:=xlWhole, MatchCase:=False, searchformat:=False)
        Set header_cell_3 = .Rows(1).Find(What:="Three", lookat:=xlWhole, MatchCase:=False, searchformat:=False)
        Set header_cell_4 = .Rows(1).Find(What:="Four", lookat:=xlWhole, MatchCase:=False, searchformat:=False)
        Set header_cell_5 = .Rows(1).Find(What:="Five", lookat:=xlWhole, MatchCase:=False, searchformat:=False)
        Set header_cell_6 = .Rows(1).Find(What:="Six", lookat:=xlWhole, MatchCase:=False, searchformat:=False)
        Set header_cell_7 = .Rows(1).Find(What:="Seven", lookat:=xlWhole, MatchCase:=False, searchformat:=False)

        col_1 = header_cell_1.Column
        col_2 = header_cell_2.Column
        col_3 = header_cell_3.Column
        col_4 = header_cell_4.Column
        col_5 = header_cell_5.Column
        col_6 = header_cell_6.Column
        col_7 = header_cell_7.Column

    End With
```

Comment: Do you have more than one workbook open when you run this code?

Comment: Only the workbook it is in and the hidden workbook in which the macros are automatically stored.

Comment: Can you please put `MsgBox ThisWorkbook.Path & vbNewLine & ThisWorkbook.Name` just above the `With Sheets("Data_Sheet")` and verify if the macro is running from the correct workbook?

Comment: You probably have to take a few actions to debug (find the source of error and fix it): 1) Use breakpoints and execute step by step, 2) Find the line that produces the error, 3) etc.

Comment: I am currently doing that @sancho.s

Comment: Leading/trailing spaces or a rogue zero-length space is my guess. Try with `lookat:=xlPart` to see if a partial match can be reached.

Comment: @MatteoNNZ I tried as you said and it appears it is using the personal workbook right now.  How would I go about fixing that?

Comment: @Jeeped Do you mean while using my find method?

Comment: If the issue may be something as simple as a trailing space character then change `lookat:=xlWhole` to `lookat:=xlPart`. If it works on a partial match then you have rogue characters somewhere. Examine the values in the worksheet closely for length, etc.

Comment: @MatteoNNZ - `ThisWorkbook` is going to return the workbook with the code in it regardless of what workbook/worksheet the code is acting on. Better to use `Sheets("Data_Sheet").parent.name`. If there was no **Sheets("Data_Sheet")** then the error would be the same but the debug would point to the With statement.

Comment: @Jeeped is right, actually we should see it with ActiveWorkbook. But Sheets("Data_sheet") should be where the debug is pointing. It's not explicitly said, but that is the only point in which the error can be prompted. Otherwise, he would rather have a Object not set error (if there's not a full match).

Comment: @MatteoNNZ - You're right of course. I just went back and confirmed the subtext of each error 9 message.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As from comments, the macro is running from the `PERSONAL.XSLB` workbook so it's trying to finding the `Sheets("Data_sheet")` in it, and clearly not finding because it is into another workbook --> `Subscript out of range`.

To fix, *always* use full references of the `Object` you work with:

```
With Workbooks("myWorkbook.xlsm").Sheets("Data_sheet") '<-- explicitly saying in which workbook it must look for the sheet

End With
```

Alternatively, remember that:

- `ThisWorkbook` references the workbook the code runs from. In your case, it would reference the `PERSONAL.XLSB`;
- `ActiveWorkbook` references the currently active workbook. Very risky to use (usually, you should know which workbook you want to target). But there might be some cases in which you want the code to intentionally running on the active workbook (see the example of an add-in: the code runs from the add-in, but you want the add-in to run on the workbook from which is used).

**WARNING:**

A common error is *not* to use any reference, like in your case:

```
With Sheets("Data_Sheet") '<-- of which workbook?
```

In that case, VBA answers the question itself with `ActiveWorkbook`, which is the default object. Only if you *explicitely* want to run from the `ActiveWorkbook` you should leave it like that; otherwise, *always* reference the object to avoid any bug related to this.

Comment: Both of the workbooks appear as ThisWorkbook.  Where would I find their exact name or should I rename them? The file is not in PERSONAL.XLSB

Comment: @Paradox does your workbook have a name (I mean, did you "Save it as"... something)? Or is a newly created one?